# Are there any schema design changes that can take a design from 4NF into a different 4NF design?

Tags: normalization

My thought/contention is that once a database schema is in 4NF it by definition can only be changed into something less than 4NF (Denormalisation, 3NF etc) and that there is no **alternative** 4NF design for it to take.

That is, once a design is in 4NF there is no design choice/change that will take it to some other different 4NF design.

**Is this correct** (or are there any cases where 2 different 4NF designs are put up for comparison or converted between)?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so except for the fact that there is a  5NF, which describes a design where your joins are only on the candidate keys.

Many "4NF" designs meet this criteria, but not all, and it is definitely something you can change a 4NF "into" to be be more normalized.

Comment: Ok there is maybe one being DB ARRAY types (aka Postgres ARRAY) - so that could be a case where the same "logical" 4NF has 2 "physical" 4NF options (Postgres ARRAY type vs a TABLE). I think that might be one.